# how to comment in HTML <![CDATA[

Tags: html, cdata

Suppose you have the following code in a `<head>`

```
<head>
  <!--
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
      SOME JS
  //]]>
  </script>
  -->
</head>
```

Is it actually commented or not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to have comment inside a CDATA section. In XML, and hence in HTML when using XHTML syntax, a [CDATA section](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect) is a used “to escape blocks of text containing characters which would otherwise be recognized as markup”. It has simple syntax: it begins with  `<![CDATA[` and ends with the `]]>`. No markup of any kind is recognized between the limiters. In HTML5, [CDATA sections in HTML syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#cdata-sections) are defined in an ad hoc manner and can only used to embed external content, namely SVG or MathML content; they may contain comments as per general XML rules, but they are no comments from HTML viewpoint, just data.

The above answers the question in the title. The question in the body seems to be different and not quite clear. The sample code contains no CDATA section at all. It contains only a `head` element containing a comment and the character data `....` (and whitespace). There is no `script` element, since data that would otherwise constitute such an element is wrapped inside a comment, hence ignored. And neither is there any CDATA section, since when parsing a comment, only the comment terminator string is recognized, no markup.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is how comments uses in HTML, here is the reference to standard http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#comments

Answer (score -2):

HTML Comment is done using

```
<!-- -->`
```

```html
<html>
<head>

    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--<script src="js/jquery_one.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->  
  </head>
  
<body>
  
<p> This is Paragraph </p>
  
  <!--<p> This is commented </p>-->

  </body>
  
  
</html>
```